# Is there a for-loop shortcut for the following?

Tags: optimization

```
// some initialization here
for (...)
{
    if (cond_a)
        stmt_a;
    else
        stmt_b;
}
if (cond_a)
    stmt_b;
```

`stmt_a` is doing some increment/setting values. `stmt_b` saves the values set by `stmt_a`. After the `for`-loop, I need to save the last values set by `stmt_a` if `cond_a` is met.

Comment: Provide more info on question.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean by "`stmt_b` saves the values set by `stmt_a`", so I recommend editing your question to clarify. In the meantime, the obvious answer is to declare a variable to hold the effects of `stmt_a` outside of the `for` statement.

```
auto a;

for (...)
{
    if (cond_a)
        //stmt_a;
        a = ...; // Store result of stmt_a
    else
        stmt_b;
}
if (cond_a)
    stmt_b;
```